# What is a good way to do parallel spice simulation?

Tags: simulation, ltspice, parallel

I'm doing a project that needs quite an amount of circuit simulations. I have access to computing clusters but have no idea how to do spice simulations in parallel (or maybe if I find a way to run spice over terminal that could a direction?)

Has anyone had experience running parallel simulations before?

I also Googled that Xyce simulator is built for similar purposes, is that the right tool to use?

Open to any suggestions.

Edit update:

The circuit i need to simulate is quite simple. but i am required to vary the parameter of a few components many times and run transient analysis. By operating one computer i can only run transient one by one which is making the progress very slow. and that is why i wonder if there is a faster way to do it in parallel?

Comment: LTspice will use all the available cores (if allowed in the control panel), but only as many at a time as it deems so (internally decided), since the overhead of parallel computation can actually slow down a simulation. Personally, I haven't found many cases where an 8/16 CPU feelt slow, and using a cluster for computing may imply having extremely complicated schematics to be worth it. That said, Xyce looks the part (haven't used it, no cluster computing in my pocket) but, if I were you, I'd first try a good computer, and only if that wasn't enough I'd aim for higher platforms.

Comment: What type of simulations are you requiring i.e. if it's just a case of varying one value a fixed amount and repeating there may be an easier solution.

Comment: @Andy aka, that is exactly the case. the circuit itself is quite simple. but i need to do study that requires me to change the variable of a few components many many times. @a concerned citizen i need to run transient analysis (a large amount of repetitions) that is why i want to run those in parallel instead of one by one

Comment: Look up Monte Carlo analysis. I don't know if LTSpice will do this because it's a bit basic but micro-cap 12 will (now free).

Comment: sounds very promising... looks like ltspice can do.. let me try it... thanks @Andy aka

Comment: @Andy aka, thanks for the advice. was able to run monte carlo on ltspice, turns out to be like using step functions on parameters... that saved me time on manually adjusting variables. but it still runs transient analysis one after another. wondering if there is any resrouce on how to take this to remote cluster or sort so i can get multiple going at the same time?

Comment: Sorry, can’t help further on this but good luck. If you were doing an ac analysis it would be different because, if it’s like micro cap, it would produce one spectrum graph with all graphs on it.